# Spring boot 2.4 - must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region

Tags: spring-boot, aws-sdk, spring-cloud, aws-java-sdk, spring-cloud-aws

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.5 and Spring Cloud 2.3.1 and referred to these docs to implement an S3 service in my Spring boot project - [spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/03/17/spring-cloud-aws-2-3-is-now-available) and [spring cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration).

My configurations are as shown below.

**pom.xml**

```
----------------------------------
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
----------------------------------
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**application.yml**

```
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      access-key: <access-key>
      secret-key: <secret-key>
    region:
      static: us-east-2
    s3:
      region: us-east-2
```

**Bean config** - Wonder why I have to create this bean, because Spring boot should have done this. But without this it said "no such bean".

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
}
```

On running the app, getting this error. What could be the issue? Please note that there might be some aws configs in my system, but I believe it will be overridden by `application.yml` values. I even deleted `~/.aws` folder and tried again, but not working.

> Error creating bean with name 'amazonS3'. Must provide an explicit
> region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region

Found this issue in many blogs, but everything points to Java AWS SDK and they all saying to configure `~/.aws` values, which I don't want to do.

Comment: You can also use environment variable `AWS_REGION` or system property `aws.region` (e.g. with `-Daws.region=us-east-2`) to specify region.

Comment: You can also try providing: `cloud.aws.region.auto=false`
`cloud.aws.stack.auto=false`